# Set store specific product attribute programmatically

Tags: magento

This code:

```
  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId(3)
    ->load(200445)
    ->setName("FooBar")
    ->save();
```

Yields exception:

> Product with the 'foo-bar' url_key attribute already exists.

Product **200445** is assigned to the website which hosts **StoreID 3**. I am emulating Admin store. Magento Enterprise 1.13.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Is faster than loading a product and saving it:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array(200445),  //array with product ids here
    array('name'=>'FooBar'), //array with attributes to update
    3 //store id.
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `url-key` attribute is automatically derived from the `name` attribute you set.  My guess is that the URL key is checked somewhere in the product save controller action, and is appended with a unique number if the URL key already exists.

You can easily do the same with your code by defining a unique URL key by using `setUrlKey('foo-bar-1')`, where `foo-bar-1` is a unique url key.

So your code would be:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId(3)
->load(200445)
->setName("FooBar")
->setUrlKey('foo-bar-1')  //Make sure this is always unique.
->save();
```

If you want to loop through products and make sure each url key you set is unique, check out some solutions here which covers that topic: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7444/593

Comment: didn't work - I tried using random string as a name, got the same error